# MUIDataTable header in the background not rendering properly when a modal is used

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal, mui-datatable

When I used a modal popup the table header in the background still floating. The header is clickable and will overlap on my modal
[image]

I found out the reason is the `-MUIDataTableHeadCell-fixedHeader` class in the header, howerver I cannot simply just remove it because it would made the sorting table not work. How should I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was the `z-index` in the `-MUIDataTableHeadCell-fixedHeader` make it goes above the background of the model, I just change the `z-index` in the model style.

However I think the more sutiable way is to customize the MUIDatatable header styles but I dont seems to get it to work that way.